# Increment/Decrement date in datepicker on mousewheel up/down respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a `datepicker`. I want to increment the date by 1 day as `mouse wheel up` is fired and decrement the date by 1 day as `mouse wheel down` is fired (upto the minimum possible date).

Below is my code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" class="calender"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()   
});
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date()); });


$('.calender').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) { 
    $id = $(this).attr('id');
    $minDate = $('#' + $id).datepicker("option", "minDate");
    $minDate = ($minDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + $minDate.getDate() + "/" + $minDate.getFullYear(); 
    $datePickerDate = $('#' + $id).datepicker("getDate");
    $datePickerDate = ($datePickerDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + $datePickerDate.getDate() + "/" + $datePickerDate.getFullYear(); 
  var days = parseInt("1", 10);

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) { 
        $datePickerDate = new Date($datePickerDate); 
        $datePickerDate = $datePickerDate.setDate($datePickerDate.getDate() + days);
    }
    else {
        if ($datePickerDate >= $minDate && $('#' + $id ).val() != "") {   
            $datePickerDate = new Date($datePickerDate);
            $datePickerDate = $datePickerDate.setDate($datePickerDate.getDate() - days);
        }
    }
    alert($datePickerDate);
    $('#' + $id).val($datePickerDate);
    $('#' + $id).datepicker("setDate", $datePickerDate);
});
```

But the `$datePickerDate` value is coming to be as `1464028200000`.

Here is the [Non-Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p4tzqLe4/5/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try another datepicker plugin which provides this feature. I think this is not a better way , because you need to care about so many things while increment date.

Comment: @Nitin - We have this datepicker for our overall application, so it cannot be changed. We have to customize the datepicker to get the desired results.

Comment: ohh..so you want consistent datepicker throughout app. have you tried moment js plugin for date manipulation, i think it will help you to simplify your task .

Comment: No. Can it be used with datepicker? Also, my datepicker is culture specific, so will it support all these functionalities?